# adding image to word document one by one with line break via vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my project, I have a macro for adding images to the document. In my userForm, i have different comboboxes and button for adding images and descriptions. When I run the macro, the second image overlaps first image like below picture. I tried to give line break after first image but i couldn't make it.

[image: word]

My userForm is like below picture.
[image: userForm]

My vba codes

```
Private Sub addLPC15_1_Click()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim mg1 As Range
    Dim mg2 As Range
    Dim objInlineShape As Shape
    Dim objShape As Shape
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    With fd
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1
        .FilterIndex = 1
        
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vItem In .SelectedItems
                Set mg2 = ActiveDocument.Range
                mg2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                doc.Shapes.AddPicture _
                  FileName:=vItem, _
                  LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                Set mg1 = ActiveDocument.Range
                mg1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                mg1.Text = "Situation: " & cmbLPC15_1.Value & vbNewLine & "Finding Type: " & cmbLPC15_11.Value & vbNewLine & "Task: " & cmbLPC15_21 & vbNewLine & "Comment: " & txtLPC15_1
            Next vItem
        End If
    End With
    For Each objInlineShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        objInlineShape.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoTrue
        objInlineShape.ScaleWidth 0.5, msoTrue
        objInlineShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
        objInlineShape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    Next objInlineShape
    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub addLPC15_2_Click()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim mg1 As Range
    Dim mg2 As Range
    Dim objInlineShape As Shape
    Dim objShape As Shape
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
    
    With fd
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1
        .FilterIndex = 1

        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vItem In .SelectedItems
                Set mg2 = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=20)
                mg2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                doc.Shapes.AddPicture _
                  FileName:=vItem, _
                  LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                  
                Set mg1 = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=21)
                mg1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                mg1.Text = "Situation: " & cmbLPC15_2.Value & vbNewLine & "Finding Type: " & cmbLPC15_12.Value & vbNewLine & "Task: " & cmbLPC15_22 & vbNewLine & "Comment: " & txtLPC15_2
            Next vItem
        End If
    End With
    For Each objInlineShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        objInlineShape.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoTrue
        objInlineShape.ScaleWidth 0.5, msoTrue
        objInlineShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
        objInlineShape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    Next objInlineShape
    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the pictures as `Shapes` which means they float over the document content. To prevent this, you either need to add them as `InlineShapes` (I would use a 2-column table to position the image and text) or specify an exact position on the page. Using an inline shape in a table would also remove the need to scale the picture.

Your loop `For Each objInlineShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes` is both confusing and unnecessary. 'AddPicture' returns either a `Shape` or an `InlineShape` depending on how it is called. So instead of the loop you can use

```
Set objShape = doc.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=vItem, _
    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
With objShape
    .ScaleHeight 0.5, msoTrue
    .ScaleWidth 0.5, msoTrue
    .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
End With
```

I would also simplify your form by only using the combo-boxes to add items to a list box. This will not only clean up the UI it will also make the coding much simpler.
[image]

However, I wouldn't use a form at all as it makes the task overly complex. Instead, I would use a Repeating Section Content Control containing the standard text and combo-boxes for the options, for example:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do it with 2-xolumn table but I have a problem place of tables. How can I set table or document ranges? For example, Range2 must start end of the table1.

Comment: @demir5334 - For example: `Set tbl = doc.Tables.Add(...)` will add a table at the end of the document, `Set row = tbl.Rows.Add()` will add a row at the end of the table. Use the Object Browser, Intellisense and Help to get further information. You would be better off creating a document template containing all the standard information and could mark locations using bookmarks. I suspect that if you used content controls you could do the whole thing with little or no code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
objInlineShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
```

to

```
objInlineShape.WrapFormat.Type =wdWrapInline
```

Comment: It worked but the descriptions comes to below the image, i want to add them right side of the image.

Comment: So, how long a description? For a few words, add a tab and your description before the line break. Otherwise, you will need to start adding the pictures inside two-column tables. The thing with wrapping is that you cannot figure out how many lines you need. You should not be using line breaks or paragraph breaks for vertical spacing in Word.

Comment: Descriptions are in first picture of my question, I want them like that.

Comment: The method built into Word for such descriptions is the Caption feature which has many benefits but is not designed to have captions next to the picture, but rather above or below. This allows an easily created table of figures. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Caption  http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - the OP is not talking about an image caption, they want to put the image side-by-side with the associated findings, as shown in the screenshot in the question.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I voted for your response right after you posted it. I still think a two-column table (which you also recommended) is the best bet for putting anything adjacent to an image and have spacing work in an elegant manner.